# resharper naming rules for xaml namespaces

Tags: xaml, namespaces, resharper, naming

In Resharper 5.0 when I use a type in XAML that I don not have a nampsace include for yet, it automatically adds the namespace as follows:

`xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.ViewModel"`

How can I force it to use abreviations like this:

`xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.ViewModel"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this article "[XAML Support Refresh in ReSharper 7.1](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/10/resharper-71-xaml-support-refresh/)", the XAML support is improved, and fix a large number of issue, including ones for namespace.

For instance, this related bug (resharper5.x) "[Code Issue "Redundant XAML namespace alias" is wrong if the namespace is used as a parameter for a markup extension.](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-198868)" has been fixed in ReSharper 7.1.